# How to clear the value of a particular text box under ng- repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my code structure.Here I have multiple roles and region text boxes accordingly.Now if I entered wrong value then how can I clear that particular text box?

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="od in default_role">
        <td>{{od.role}}</td>
        <td>
            <datalist id="all_region_list"> <option data-ng-repeat="or in list_region" value="{{or}}"> </datalist>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="region" list="all_region_list" placeholder="Region" title="Region" ng-keyup='get_region_values("Region");' ng-blur='location_value_check("Region",region,$index)'>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the model's property (which is connected to the particular textbox) value to ''. So it will clear the textbox.

Demo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    {
      name: 'name1'
    },
    {
      name: 'name2'
    },
    {
      name: 'name3'
    },
    {
      name: 'name4'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="name" /></td>
      <td><button ng-click="item.name = ''">Clear textbox</button></td>
      <td>Model: {{item | json }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you want to just clear the textbox without changing the model:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [
    {
      name: 'name1'
    },
    {
      name: 'name2'
    },
    {
      name: 'name3'
    },
    {
      name: 'name4'
    }
  ];

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      $(this).parents('tr').first().find('input').val('');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="name" /></td>
      <td><button>Clear textbox</button></td>
      <td>Model: {{item | json }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```